# Unable to load password for provider in Terraform using vault_secret_generic

Tags: openstack, terraform, hashicorp-vault

I have a terraform that builds a VM using the Openstack provider. The username and password for the provider are being stored in a Hashicorp Vault secret. I've set up my plan to enable the `vault` provider and access the secret using my privileged token. Here's what my plan looks like:

```
provider "vault" {
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "openstack" {
  path = "secret/openstack"
}

provider "openstack" {
  user_name = "${data.vault_generic_secret.openstack.data["username"]}"
  password = "${data.vault_generic_secret.openstack.data["password"]}"
  tenant_name = "${var.openstack_tenant_name}"
  domain_id = "${var.openstack_domain_id}"
  auth_url = "${var.openstack_auth_url}"
}
```

When I try to run this plan I get the following error:

```
* provider.openstack: You must provide a password to authenticate
```

So far I've been able to verify that the `vault` provider and `vault_generic_secret` data item work in a different plan by displaying my secret values as output variables. Additionally, I know the openstack provider plan works because I'm able to hard code the user_name and password with the proper values and the plan works fine.

It seems to me that even though the `data.vault_generic_secret.openstack` vertex is being walked before my `provider.openstack` vertex (verified this in TF_LOG TRACE output), the data values aren't fully loaded or available to use at this point. My reason for thinking this is because when I tested leaving the password/username fields blank I see the same error. But if I set the username and password to invalid credentials I get a completely different error that it fails to authenticate against the actual openstack auth url.

```
* provider.openstack: Authentication failed
```

Has anyone every used vault to load secrets to configure their VM provider? Any input people might have would be a huge help.

Terraform v0.9.2

**Update 1:**

I found some terraform issues that appear to be related to what I'm experiencing:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11264
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12393

Based on the first issue, when I tried running `terraform plan -input=false` it works.

Comment: This does indeed look like an example of the bug you linked to in your Update 1. This bug was fixed in v0.9.3, so you may find that upgrading Terraform is enough to get this to work as expected. If not, this looks like a new bug that you could file in the Terraform github issues.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'll try to upgrade and see if that helps.